# Alterar o container de uma form customizada

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Fiz uma form customizada, com o estilo do Windows 10, mas tem um problema, ela está considerando a barra caption como parte do painel do cliente da form.

[image: Essa]

Essa é a form. O problema é que, a posição 0, 0 da form está dentro do Caption, onde não poderia ficar, devia ser abaixo do Caption; segue o exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, como eu modifico a área do cliente da janela? (Área onde os controles podem ser postos)

Comment: Por que não insere um `Panel`?

Comment: O Panel se torna "Locked", o usuário não consegue adicionar nem editar o painel...